# Consecutive Mordell Curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, mordell-curves

Are there infinitely many $k$ such that the Mordell curves $x^3 = y^2 + k$ and $x^3 = y^2 + k + 1$ both have no solutions?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if this question isn't open. But assuming standard conjectures, I think the answer should be yes.